# .NET BackgroundWorker: I don't understand how ReportProgress works

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I created a BackgroundWorker (`mainBw`) in my UI (WPF) thread. It has an infinite loop where it sleeps for 1.5 sec and calls a function via `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` which just outputs text from the "global" `text` variable to a TextBox.

Also before the loop it created another (`child`) BackgroundWorker which ReportsProgress, in ProgressChanged event handler it modifies the `text` variable.

I thought that it will not work because there is no anything like WinForms Application.DoEvents() in the `mainBw` loop so it can't process the event handler. But it works. Why?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication6
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private BackgroundWorker mainBw = new BackgroundWorker();

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainBw.DoWork += MainBwOnDoWork;

            mainBw.RunWorkerAsync();

            btn.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private string text = "abc";

        private void MainBwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

            bw.DoWork += BwOnDoWork;
            bw.ProgressChanged += BwOnProgressChanged;
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1500);

                text += " main ";

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { WriteToUIThread(); }));
            }
        }

        private void WriteToUIThread()
        {
            tbox.Text = DateTime.Now + " " + text + Environment.NewLine + tbox.Text;
        }

        private void BwOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            text += e.UserState.ToString();
        }

        private void BwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(0, "child");
            }

        }
    }
}

    // XAML
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btn" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="105" Margin="43,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <TextBox Name="tbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="114" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Margin="27,182,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Because the UI thread is not being locked. Once the `BwOnProgressChanged` function has finished, the UI thread is free to update the display (or there abouts, it may have to do some other minor things in between)

Comment: @musefan, as I understood, the event is processed in the mainBw thread, not in the UI thread. If I do something like this 

    tbox.Text = "child"; 

in the ProgressChanged event, it will throw exception.

Comment: Really?  tbox.Text = "child"; in the ProgressChanged event throws an  exception?

Comment: @Blam, yes. it throws InvalidOperationException with message `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`. You can run and see it on your own.

Comment: @Blam The second BGW is created in the work handler of the first BGW, so it doesn't have a SynchronizationContext to capture, so it's methods all fire in thread pool threads.

Comment: @Servy I only see one BackgroundWorker and it is named mainBw.

Comment: @Blam Then look a little closer.  If you're really struggling then just ctrl + F for "new BackgroundWorker()" and let your browser point it out to you.

Comment: @Servy OH, thanks now I see it.   That just seems like a strange way to do it.

Comment: @Blam It very much *is* a strange way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I know :) This code is just for demo/testing purposes. Actually I want to create some threads in my mainBw background thread and they should report progress to the mainBw thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BackgroundWorker uses a universal way to get code to run on the UI thread, it uses the static [SynchronizationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to find a synchronization provider.  ReportProgress() uses its Post() method to marshal the call.

If you run a Winforms app then the Current property will reference an instance of [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx).  Automatically installed when you create a Form or call Application.Run().  It uses Control.Begin/Invoke() to implement the Post and Send methods.

And if you run a WPF app then the Current property will reference an instance of [DispatcherSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext.aspx), it uses Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke().

So this just works automagically.

Comment: He never utilizes this functionality at all.  The only BGW that actually has a captured sync context only ever handles the do work event.

Comment: Yes, as explained in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx it was using the default ThreadPool SynchonizationContext.

Answer (score 1):

It works because the `BackgroundWorker` does work in a background thread (hence the name).  Since it's not running in the UI thread, it's not blocking the UI thread, it is just sending short methods to be run in the UI thread every once in a while.

That said, it's still not a particularly well designed approach to solving the problem.  If you want to run some code every 3 seconds just use a `Timer` instead.  If you use the timer in the `Forms` namespace it will fire it's event in the UI thread on your behalf.

Comment: See my comment above, as I understood it gets marshalled to the mainBw thread, not to the UI thread (because it was created in the mainBw thread).

And Timer that's not what I want, this code is just for demo/testing purposes. Actually I want to create some threads in my mainBw background thread and they should reports progress to the mainBw thread.

Comment: @Alex11223 As Hans says in his answer, the BGW looks at the current synchronization context and uses that to marshal the non-worker event handlers to that context.  Your first BGW **has no context** and so the child BGW's events will all fire in thread pool threads.  They won't fire in the first BGW's threads because it doesn't create a `SynchronizationContext` that would allow that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It works, because the `BackgroundWorker` runs - as its name says - in a background thread independently fromo the main UI thread.

The `ReportProgress`-event gets marshalled to the UI thread so that this event can easily be handled, without calling `Invoke`-methods on the controls involved.

Contraray, the `Application.DoEvents()`-method in WinForms allowed the process to handle other messages for perfoming long going operations in main thread, *without* using a background thread.

Comment: See my comment above, as I understood it gets marshalled to the mainBw thread, not to the UI thread (because it was created in the mainBw thread).